# AWS Gov Cloud application load balancer authenticate rule with Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cognito, aws-application-load-balancer

In AWS' commercial cloud (us-west-2), I can create an ALB listener rule on my HTTPS (443) listener to first authenticate to a Cognito user pool (with OIDC integration Azure AD) and then forward to an Ec2 instance after successful authentication.

I try the same things in gov cloud (gov-west-1), and there is no option to Authenticate in a Load Balance listener rule with Cognito, only pure OIDC authentication.

Does this feature exist in Gov cloud?

I'm specifically discussing the attached "insert rule" UI shown in the image.  In my gov cloud account (gov-west-2), "Amazon Cognito" is not an option in the "1. Authentucate" dropdown.  The only option that exists is "OIDC"

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature is sadly not yet available in GovCloud (see [this doc on govcloud-differences](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/govcloud-us/latest/UserGuide/govcloud-elb.html#govcloud-elb-diffs)), but you can get around this by setting up an OIDC auth action directed to your Cognito User Pool (which is able to act as a standard OIDC provider).

This auth action requires you to provide OIDC endpoints which are described for AWS Cognito at the following docs page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-userpools-server-contract-reference.html

This does require you to set up a User Pool App Client, configured with a Client Secret, as well as a User Pool Domain.

Lastly, make sure to configure your CallbackURLs for the Cognito Client to allow redirects back to the `/oauth2/idpresponse` endpoint on your Load Balancer; e.g. for a Load Balancer at `<DNS>`, use CallbackURL: `https://DNS/oauth2/idpresponse`.

When you configure the auth action, you will need to supply the following details:

- **Authenticate**: `OIDC`
- **Issuer**: `https://cognito-idp.us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com/us-gov-west-1_abc123`
- **Authorization endpoint**: `https://my-cognito-domain.auth-fips.us-gov-west-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize`
- **Token endpoint**: `https://my-cognito-domain.auth-fips.us-gov-west-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token`
- **User info endpoint**: `https://my-cognito-domain.auth-fips.us-gov-west-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/userInfo`
- **Client ID**: `abcdef123456`
- **Client secret**: `hunter7`

Sample CloudFormation snippet follows:

```yaml
Parameters:
  SessionTimeout:
    Description: The maximum duration of the authentication session, in seconds.
    Type: Number
    Default: 604800  # One day
    MinValue: 60
    MaxValue: 604800
  CognitoClientID:
    Description: Client ID from pre-configured cognito environment
    Type: String
    NoEcho: true
  CognitoClientSecret:
    Description: Client Secret from pre-configured cognito environment
    Type: String
    NoEcho: true
  CognitoProviderUrl:
    Description: Provider URL from pre-configured cognito environment
    Type: String
  CognitoDomainName:
    Description: Domain Name from pre-configured cognito environment
    Type: String
  TargetGroupArn:
    Description: ARN of the Target Group for forwarding traffic
    Type: String

Conditions:
  IsGovCloud: !Not [!Equals ['aws', !Ref AWS::Partition]]

Resources:
  AuthenticatedListenerRule:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule
    Properties:
      Actions:
        - Type: authenticate-oidc
          Order: 1
          AuthenticateOidcConfig:
            ClientId: !Ref CognitoClientID
            ClientSecret: !Ref CognitoClientSecret
            Issuer: !Ref CognitoProviderUrl
            UserInfoEndpoint:
              Fn::Sub:
                - https://${CognitoDomainName}.${AuthSuffix}.${AWS::Region}.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/userInfo
                - AuthSuffix: !If [IsGovCloud, "auth-fips", "auth"]
            AuthorizationEndpoint:
              Fn::Sub:
                - https://${CognitoDomainName}.${AuthSuffix}.${AWS::Region}.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize
                - AuthSuffix: !If [IsGovCloud, "auth-fips", "auth"]
            TokenEndpoint:
              Fn::Sub:
                - https://${CognitoDomainName}.${AuthSuffix}.${AWS::Region}.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token
                - AuthSuffix: !If [IsGovCloud, "auth-fips", "auth"]
            OnUnauthenticatedRequest: authenticate
            Scope: openid
            SessionTimeout: !Ref SessionTimeout
        - Type: forward
          Order: 2
          TargetGroupArn:
            Ref: TargetGroup
```

Best of luck and let's hope for expanded GovCloud features soon

Comment: Thank you!  yes, I did end up going with OIDC integration (directly to my IdP without Cognito).  I had forgotten I posted this so thanks for posting the answer!